# prove equality - definite integral of definite integral

Tags: definite-integrals

I need help to prove this expression.
I can check that it is correct but can not prove it. Please help.

$$\int_0^x \int_0^t f(v) dv dt = \int_0^x (x-t) f(t) dt $$

Comment: How do you check that it is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Integrate by parts:
$$ \int_0^x \int_0^t f(v) \, dv \, dt = \left[ (t-x) \int_0^t f(v) \, dv \right]_0^x - \int_0^x (t-x) f(t) \, dt, $$
by carefully choosing $t-x$ as an antiderivative of $ 1 $. Then the term in brackets vanishes and you have the formula you wanted.